# How to target the initial revision of a node?

Tags: nodes

How to target the initial revision of a node?

This gives me a list of node IDs in which the latest revision of the node is of author `$user->id()`:

```php
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
$query->condition('uid', $user->id());
$author_nids = $query->execute();
```

I would like the same but for nodes in which the initial revision was created by `$user->id()`.

Comment: My understanding is that the 'uid' doesn't change, it's always the original author. There's a 'revision_uid' property on the base revision table if you need to query by the revision author instead. So in answer to your question, can you inspect the data? Is something changing the 'uid'?

Comment: has it always been that behaviour throughout all the drupal8 versions? I am not sure . Do u know how to do the drupal query to get the first revision_uid?

Comment: the uid change when you edit a content and change "Authored by"

Comment: that uid is contradictory with the initial revision or the last revision of the revision table depending what that node table uid shall be

Comment: for all revisions $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
$query->condition('revision_uid', $user->id());
$author_nids = $query->execute();